# pandas read_csv not converting string to date

Tags: python, date, csv, pandas

I've looked for help on this one and didn't find the answer (i'm sure i'm asking the wrong question)

I have a CSV file, it has dates in it, when i read it in, the date conversion doesn't happen.

```
import pandas
df = pd.read_csv('file', index_col='Sequence', parse_dates='Date')
```

CSV file

```
Sequence,Date,Unit,Name,Indexed,Arbitrated,Redo
1,2013-01-01,Aloha,first last,831,0,0
```

df.Date is a bunch of strings not datetime values

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the column to parse as a list, not a string:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file', index_col='Sequence', parse_dates=['Date'])
```

The docstring explanation for `parse_dates` says *"list of ints or names"*, as in this way you can specify multiple columns to parse. But I have to agree that for one column it is a bit surprising.

Comment: Oh for heavens sake, it can't be that simple :) What a newb. Thanks so much for the help. I just kept staring at it and couldn't see that forest through the trees.